# If 75% of radioactive material remains, how many half-lives have elapsed?

Tags: measurements, radioactivity

Radioactive element `A` radioactively decays into material `B`. If 75% of `A` and 25% of `B` are present, how many half-lives of material `A` have elapsed?

I was recently taught that the correct answer is "one half of a half-life has elapsed". However, due to the fact that the amount of radioactive material remaining scales exponentially (logarithmically) instead of in a linear fashion, wouldn't the answer be less than one half of a half-life?

Comment: It doesn't scale quadratically, but rather exponentially (logarithmically).

Comment: "I was taught that the correct answer is..." - you were taught badly (and you realize it which is good). Not only was the given answer wrong - the question was poorly phrased. In most instances element B would not be stable - and the only information you need is what percentage of A remains. Then again, determination of age often relies on ratios of isotopes present - but do realize you need to know the half life of the entire chain, not just the parent, in order to do the math correctly.

Comment: This is a math question.

Comment: For future visitors, this task can be facilitated on a TI-83 calculator or above using this program: http://tibasic.com/science/earth-science/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

@gerrit provided a formula, but without stating the reasoning behind it.

Radioactive decay is an exponential function.  After $n$ half-lives, the amount of the original material remaining is

$$\textrm{amount remaining after}\ n\ \textrm{half-lives} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

Therefore, you want to solve

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \frac{3}{4}\\
\log_\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \log_\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}\\
n &= \frac{\log \frac{3}{4}}{\log \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\log \frac{3}{4}}{- \log 2}
   \approx 0.415
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are entirely correct.  But I like graphical representations.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay we see the decay formula is:

$$N(t) = N_0e^\frac{-t}{τ}$$

Where N<sub>0</sub> is the starting number of nuclides and τ is the mean lifetime.  We also see that the half-life is

$$t_{1/2} = τ ln(2)$$

Substituting for τ, we get:

$$N(t) = N_0e^\frac{-tln(2)}{t_{1/2}}$$

So for example if we have N<sub>0</sub> = 1000 and t<sub>1/2</sub> = 100 we can plot the following graph:

[image: Exponential decay plot]

<sub>Note that the horizontal axis is the t-axis.</sub>

We see the following:

- At t=100 (one half life), N(t) is 500, half of 1000, as expected
- At t=200 (two half lives), N(t) is 250, 1/4 of 1000, as expected
- We intersect the curve with a line at N(t) = 750.  Here we can see this occurs at about t=41.5 as predicted by the other answers.

Comment: *Here we can see this occurs at about t=41.5 as predicted by the other answers.* If you can see, that is. This site is overly-reliant on imagery. Good answers should be accessible to those who can't see / can't see very well.

Answer (score 15):

You can use simple logarithms to calculate the answer.  The number of half-lives that have elapsed can be calculated with

$$
 - \frac{\log{f}}{\log{2}}
$$

where $f$ is the fraction that remains.

So plugging in the numbers gives

$$
- \frac{\log(0.75)}{\log(2)} = 0.415 = 41.5\%
$$

Comment: It feels odd to express the number of half-lives as a percentage.